# Mongoose dynamic query in find with $in is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Node.js and Mongoose 5+ to dynamically build a query in the database. The variable `filterField` is the field name and `filterValues` is an array. So, my code is like this:

```
if (req.currentUser.activePage) {
    queryParam['pageId'] = req.currentUser.activePage;
    if (filterField && filterValues)
        queryParam[filterField] = { $in: filterValues };
    query = Model.find(queryParam);
    console.info(queryParam);
}
Model.paginate(query, options, async (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.errmsg });
    } else {
        res.status(200).json(result.docs);
    }
});
```

The printed `queryParam` is as follow:

```
{ pageId: '123', id: { '$in': [ 1, 2 ] } }
```

If I run this query directly in the Mongo shell it works fine.

However, when I run this query in Mongoose, it does not return anything when the `id: {$in ..` is present.

What is the error?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the schema for your model and an example document that you expect the query to return?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I inspected the code a bit longer and figured out the problem is with a plugin I am using with Mongoose, the mongoose-paginate. I tested the query without this plugin and it worked fine. Thanks for the tip to show more of the code, because of that I saw that I was not using pure mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

you have passed wrong parameter query to `Model.paginate()` method ,try this way :

```
if (req.currentUser.activePage) {
    queryParam['pageId'] = req.currentUser.activePage;
    if (filterField && filterValues){ 
        queryParam[filterField] = { '$in': filterValues };
    }
    Model.paginate(queryParam, options, async (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.errmsg });
       } else {
        res.status(200).json(result.docs);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code which you have written, it will help the future visitor.

Comment: What's different here? The only change I see is `$in` to `'$in'`which is treated identically in JS.

Comment: This code is pretty same as the code from the question. Notice that the `$in` operator is converted to `'$in'` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error, it is caused by the [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate) plugin. So, if you are using this plugin with Mongoose, be careful with the parameters you pass to the query.

In my case, passing an array as filter with the option `$in` does not work with `mongoose-paginate`.